# Determine the set $|z-1|^2+\bar z-1=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The solution states that  $|z-1|^2+(\bar z-1)=0$ if and only if $(z-1)(\bar z-1)+(z-1)=0$

since $|z|^2=z\bar z $ and if we consider a new $z'=z-1$ then we'll have 
$$|z-1|^2 = |z'|^2= z'\bar z'=(z-1)(\bar z-1)$$
and it makes sense but why can we remove the bar from the second part?

Comment: You mean, why $\overline{z-1}=\overline{z}-1$?

Comment: why does $(\bar z -1) = (z−1)$ i think it's not true unless z is real

Comment: @MouneBenGhanem it doesn't but the definition of modulus from $z \bar{z} = |z|^{2}$ gives $|z-1|^2=(\bar{z}-1)(z-1)$ as $\overline{z-1}=\bar{z}-1$

Comment: well yeah that's what i explained in my question, i do understand that part but since the solution states that $|z−1|^2 + (\bar z -1)=0$ means that $ (z−1).(\bar z−1)+(z−1) = 0 $where did that $ (z−1)$  come from or is there a mistake in my book?

Comment: It's probably a typo, but it doesn't make things wrong. For $\overline{0} = 0$, hence $\lvert z-1\rvert^2 + \overline{z} - 1 = 0 \iff \lvert z-1\rvert^2 + z-1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of setting $w=z-1$ is good; observe that $\bar{z}-1=\overline{z-1}=\bar{w}$, so the equation is
$$
|w|^2+\bar{w}=0
$$
Now remember that $|w|^2=w\bar{w}$, so the equation is
$$
w\bar{w}+1\cdot\bar{w}=0
$$
or
$$
(w+1)\bar{w}=0
$$
Thus either $\bar{w}=0$, that is, $z=1$, or $w=-1$, that is, $z=0$.

You can also observe that the original equation holds if and only if
$$
|z-1|^2+z-1=0
$$
by conjugating both terms. Writing $|z-1|^2=(z-1)(\overline{z-1})$, we get
$$
(z-1)(\overline{z-1}+1)=0
$$
so either $z=1$ or $\bar{z}-1+1=0$, hence $z=0$.

---

Suppose the equation is $|z-u|^2+\bar{z}-\bar{u}=0$, where now $u$ is an arbitrary complex number. The solution would work the same: set $w=z-u$, so the equation becomes
$$
w\bar{w}+\bar{w}=0
$$
This becomes $\bar{w}(w+1)=0$, so either $w=0$ or $w=-1$.

Comment: So whether z is real or not the results are still the same but i still think that it should've been clarified in the book.

Comment: @MouneBenGhanem The key is that $|z|$ is real, so it remains the same when conjugating.

Comment: does $|\bar z| = \bar z  z$ and does putting a bar on each side of the equation not change the result? if so it would make much more sense to me.

Comment: I mean $|\bar z|^2$

Comment: @MouneBenGhanem If you write $z=x+iy$, then $|z|=|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+(-y)^2}=|x-iy|=|\bar{z}|$. By definition this is real and doesn't change when conjugating.

Comment: Well yeah after i thought about it's the same, thank you very much for the help my confusion is now cleared.

Answer (score 1):

From the given equation it follows that $\bar z$ is real, and so is $z$. In this case $|z-1|^2=(z-1)^2$, so that the equation now reads
$$0=(z-1)^2+z-1=z(z-1)\ ,$$
with obvious solutions.